# Sed command garbled Error

Tags: shell, sed, solaris

I am trying to get the data between 15 minute from the log file but sed is not working and it generating sed: command garbled: / 38 error. Here 38 was the value of min1.

```
Current_Time_in_Seconds=`date +"%T" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'`

subtract_mins() {
Fifteen_minute_before=`expr $Current_Time_in_Seconds - $1`
echo $Fifteen_minute_before
}

Change_Time_into_Seconds() {
Fifteen_minute_before1=`subtract_mins $1`
sec=`expr  $Fifteen_minute_before1 % 60`
i=`expr  $Fifteen_minute_before1 / 60`
min=`expr  $i % 60`
hrs=`expr  $i / 60`
timestamp=`(printf "%d:%02d:%02d" $hrs $min $sec)`
echo "$min $hrs"
}


sDate= date +"%d-%b-%y"
Curr_hrs=`date +"%T" |awk -F: '{ print ($1)}'`
Curr_min=`date +"%T" |awk -F: '{ print ($2)}'`


timestamp=`Change_Time_into_Seconds 900`
hrs1=`echo $timestamp | cut -f 2`
min1=`echo $timestamp | cut -f 1`
sed -n '/'$sDate' '$hrs1':'$min1':[0-6][0-9]/,/'$sDate' '$Curr_hrs':'$Curr_min':[0-6][0-9]/p' /srvrs/mvprd/bea/user_projects/domains/mvwlp_prd/servers/mvwlp_s1/logs/mvwlp_s1_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log> /srvrs/mvprd/scripts/MultiVU_Service_count/output/out_1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to double quote your variables:

```
sed -n '/'"$sDate"' '"$hrs1"':'"$min1"':[0-6][0-9]/,/'"$sDate"' '"$Curr_hrs"':'"$Curr_min"':[0-6][0-9]/p' /srvrs/mvprd/bea/user_projects/domains/mvwlp_prd/servers/mvwlp_s1/logs/mvwlp_s1_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log> /srvrs/mvprd/scripts/MultiVU_Service_count/output/out_1.txt
```

or just enclose your sed command in double quotes :

```
sed -n "/$sDate $hrs1:$min1:[0-6][0-9]/,/$sDate $Curr_hrs:$Curr_min:[0-6][0-9]/p" /srvrs/mvprd/bea/user_projects/domains/mvwlp_prd/servers/mvwlp_s1/logs/mvwlp_s1_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log> /srvrs/mvprd/scripts/MultiVU_Service_count/output/out_1.txt
```

Comment: Its not working actually now it is not saying that sed is grabled but the output is not coming

Comment: Maybe no match in your file for this pattern.

Comment: @ Kenavoz I have searched the pattern it was there but the problem is in the line where I am spliting the string :-
    timestamp=`Change_Time_into_Seconds 900`
   hrs1=`echo $timestamp | cut -f 2`
   min1=`echo $timestamp | cut -f 1`

this two are not able to get the correct values